# javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection timed out (Read failed) for IMAP

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail

Please help me resolve this exception. I am running this IMAP email listener in my Spring Boot Java application to retrieve emails from my gmail inbox

```
 return IntegrationFlows
         .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(imapUrl())
                   .autoStartup(true)
                   .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*")
                                             .put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"))
                   .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(false)
                   .shouldDeleteMessages(false)
                   .shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)
                   .autoCloseFolder(false))
         .handle(m-> myService.process(MimeMessage))
         .get();
```

Occasionally I am getting the follow exception in a higher environment

```
 javax.mail.FolderClosedException: * BYE JavaMail Exception:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.handleIdle(IMAPFolder.java:3316)
```

leading to

```
2020-05-20 18:06:27.264  WARN 1 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.i.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter        : Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.
```

I was wondering how you would recommend handling this issue? by poking the gmail server with a 'mail.timeout' property? Or is there another recommended method? Thanks again!

Comment: Occasional network failures are a reality on the internet.  Your system should be able to recover and reconnect and resume.  There's no way to guarantee your socket will stay up 24/7.  Make sure your (springs?) idle handler pokes the server at least every 29 minutes to keep IDLE alive.

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for responding! How would you recommend poking the gmail server using the function above? Apologies if it is clear, or if the question can be better asked. thank you. I tried adding "mail.timeout" and "mail.imaps.timeout" and "mail.imaps.connectiontimeout" to automatically trigger a timeout so that IMAP automatically reconnects but that didnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

See comment from Max. I agree: it is really normal that we get a connection loss.
See that warn message:

> Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in 10000 milliseconds.

And it does by logic:

```
this.receivingTask = scheduler.schedule(new ReceivingTask(), this.receivingTaskTrigger);
```

...

```
private class ReceivingTask implements Runnable {

    ReceivingTask() {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isRunning()) {
            try {
                ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this.idleTask.run();
                logger.debug("Task completed successfully. Re-scheduling it again right away.");
            }
            catch (Exception e) { //run again after a delay
                if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                    logger.warn("Failed to execute IDLE task. Will attempt to resubmit in "
                            + ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this.reconnectDelay + " milliseconds.", e);
                }
                ImapIdleChannelAdapter.this.receivingTaskTrigger.delayNextExecution();
                publishException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Arten thank you for the response. The issue is that it is unable to reconnect after this attempted reconnection for quite some time, and when it does eventually reconnect, it does not pick up the emails anymore. Not sure the proper way to handle this, any ideas?

Comment: Hm. What Spring Integration version do you use? Try with the latest one - `5.3.0`

Comment: I am currently using 5.2.5, will switch to the latest and see if anything changs, thank you.

Comment: Yes, please. The latest in that line is `5.2.6` any way

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. Do you think there is a chance it is because i am using 'imap' instead of 'imaps' in the properties?

Comment: Have no idea... I'm not so good in mail API, esspecially GMail specifics...